# Getting the transaction hash after sending a method to track the status

Tags: javascript, solidity, nft

I am trying to add some extra functionality to my NFT minting dApp and check if a mint/transaction is actually succesful before executing a certain line of code. But i cant really connect the dots on this.

I found alot of examples to get the status by using the txn hash, but one first has to obtain this transaction hash right? Is there a way of obtaining the txn hash after starting up/confirming the transaction? This is the actual code where i send the transaction to the mint method in my contract:

```
const mint = async function (amount) { 
   const id = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_chainId' });
  if (mintAcc != "")
  {
    var totalCost = WEI_COST * amount;
    // if an account is present
    if (mintAcc.length > 0 && id == CHAIN_ID) { 
      
     contract.methods.mint(amount).send({
        from: mintAcc[0],
        to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        value: String(totalCost),
       });
    }
  } else { 
    alert("Connect wallet first")
  }
}
```

What should i add to obtain the transaction hash/id after actually sending the mint method to track its status if its mined or not?

The reason im asking this is because im using an allowlist stored in a map which holds the value how many mints a specific adress can claim. After the claim took place i want to remove the persons adress so they cannot claim again.

Answer (score 0):

The `send()` method returns a `PromiEvent` type that you can handle events on. One of these events is `transactionHash`

Code example:

```
contract.methods.mint(amount).send({
    from: mintAcc[0],
    to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    value: String(totalCost),
}).on("transactionHash", function(hash) {
    console.log(hash);
});
```

Docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

Comment: Thanks alot for your response and pointing me in the right direction to elarn about using the PromiEvents, this is exactly what i was looking for.